# Get hash element with maximal value in clojure

Tags: clojure, hashmap

How to find a maximal valued element in clojure hashmap?
Assume there's a following hashmap:

```
{:a 1 :b 3 :c 4 :d 18 :e 9}
```

In this case we need :d as a result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess it's your solution

```
(key (apply max-key val {:a 1 :b 3 :c 4 :d 18 :e 9}))
-> :d
```

Comment: @amolloy how does the above work. The val function receives a vector [:a 1] etc. So how does val work on a vector ?